# How exactly does the Kitsune Mask work?

Tags: sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin

How exactly does the Kitsune Mask work?

It seems that the colors emitted are how close you are to a treasure box, in order of Green, Blue, Yellow... And it seems to go through walls?

But there then there's a bit of inconsistency on when it triggers?

For instance, when I'm trying to find the Bough in Rockfall Passage, and in the tunnel where there's two rocks dropping close to each other, there's a point where I'm standing on the ground and the aura is yellow, with it going green just a few steps away.

I presume that means that wherever the treasure is, I'm standing right on top of it, **but** if I reload my autosave and stand there again, sometimes the auras don't appear. And I've waited 10 seconds?

Well, I was wrong in the treasure's location, but still, the aura is inconsistent? ... The treasure was:

> Above me.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here... you answer how the mask works yourself in the question (progressing proximity based colors when near a treasure)

Comment: @Rapitor - It *appears* to work by proximity, but, then, why does it only seem to trigger some times, and not others, and why does a few steps, change it from Yellow, all the way to Green? I guess if I'm at the very edge of the detection range, for the latter, but the wide range where Yellow happens, seems to invalidate that idea.